# It's an indefinite integral $\int\frac{x^2(1- \ln(x))}{(\ln(x))^4-x^4}\,dx.$

Tags: integration, logarithms

> $$\int\frac{x^2(1- \ln(x))}{(\ln(x))^4-x^4}\,dx.$$

I try to solve it by factoring, but got stuck in the problem. Please help anyone.

Comment: Please check my edit and show your work!

Comment: Have you tried using partial fractions?

Comment: Use of partial fraction can be done when we have one variable but here are two lnx and x

Comment: @Anshdeepsingh $$(\ln^4(x)-x^4)=(\ln(x)-x)(\ln(x)+x)(\ln^2(x)+x^2)$$ by $$y^4-x^4=(y^2-x^2)(y^2+x^2)=(y-x)(y+x)(y^2+x^2)$$

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in the factoring..

Comment: I tried to reduce power of denominator firstly in square then linear but get no advantage to solve

Comment: you can add this information into the question by [edit]ing it. Most people do not go through all the comments..

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

After cheating with WA, here is the solution: notice that "by magic",
$$\int\frac{x^2(1-\log x)}{(\log x)^4-x^4}dx
=\int\frac{\dfrac{1-\log x}{x^2}}{\dfrac{(\log x)^4}{x^4}-1}dx
=\int\frac1{\dfrac{(\log x)^4}{x^4}-1}d\frac{\log x}x.$$

Now

$$\frac1{u^4-1}=\frac1{4 (u-1)} -\frac 1{4 (1 + u)} - \frac1{2 (1 + u^2)}$$ which is easy to integrate.

Comment: wow! would have never thought like this

Comment: @Quantum: when you see such a contrived integral in an exercise, this is a sign that... there is an easy solution.

Comment: @Quantum: and when you see that in real life, this is a sign that... you are bust !

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=\frac{\ln x }{x}$ then $du = \frac{1 - \ln x }{x^2} dx$ so $dx =\frac{x^2 du}{1-\ln x } $
$$\int \frac{x^2 (1-\ln x )}{x^4 (u^4-1)}\frac{x^2 du}{1-\ln x } $$